# Android Webview - Webpage must fit the screen

Tags: android, webview, click, android-webview

I have tried the following to fit the web page based on the device screen size. But after code the text fields and drop down buttons are not working. Can anyone help me?

```
WebView myWebView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);         
     WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
     myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
     myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.immigrer.com/potentiel"); 

     myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
}
```

Comment: please can anyone help?

Comment: Plz upload one snap what u tried and what u want?

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to is designed to fit the screen by default. You should try setting `setUseWideViewPort(true)` as that makes the WebView pay attention to the site's viewport meta tag. Also, the `LayoutAlgorithm` setting might be messing things up: try using `LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `downloadListener` or use `onPageStarted()` and check if your webview ends with '.pdf'.(Assuming your URL, which contains a PDF is ending with '.pdf'. Else check any qualifier you are using in all your URLs where you expect a PDF to download, and then pass on that URL to `AsyncTask` to download.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the link with the following settings:

```
WebSettings s = getSettings();
s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
s.setSavePassword(true);
s.setSaveFormData(true);
s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
s.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
s.setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);


// enable navigator.geolocation 
s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("");

// enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

I was able to use text fields and drop down buttons. Some settings are irrelevant but hey it works